# Delete accounts associated with my Gmail address

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have a Gmail address, which somehow has a many (about 20) email addresses associated with it. I followed some instructions from somewhere and managed to get Gmail to email me a list of all the email addresses that claim my address is associated with them.

However, I cannot find a way to remove all these associations. How can I remove all these associations?

Answer (score 1):

Log in to Gmail from your browser of choice and click on the **settings icon** (the gear in the upper right-hand corner) and select **Settings**.

Go to the **Accounts** tab and you should see a list of all the associated email accounts.

In my example below, I have my primary Gmail account on top, followed by an associated Hotmail account.

Click the **delete** option on the right, and you can remove the account association.

[image]

Comment: None of the accounts that take it upon themselves to say that they're associated to my email address, show up there.

Comment: I think the question then is whether that list you have is accurate, or if it even means anything.  Can you provide the method you followed to obtain it so we can analyze it/try it for ourselves?